# Automate backup Azure Webapp wwwroot directory to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-webapps

I am hosted Wordpress muultisite on Azure Linux  webapp. My upload folder is 26 GB. So I need to back up the upload folder to azure blob storage.

Azure web app backup supports max 10GB and snapshot supports 30GB. therefore I need to backup the upload folder and restore it when needed.

So what is the best method to backup the upload folder?

I don't like to use Azure blob storage and map it to webapp because it needs a wordpress plugin.

Comment: These might be of use https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18531 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca9f198f-2d33-42a9-9c6e-e5df501f64a0/azure-web-app-backup-exceeded-max-size-of-10-gb?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: yes @JasonEvans Snapshot supports 30GB. my concern is if the region is down how can I restore the web app? So I need to backup wwwroot to another region

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebappbackup?view=azps-6.4.0

you may try the powershell az commands to backups azure web app.

Pls refer the above documentation site.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I tried these commands. but these commands are not working because the webapp size is 27 GB. This works when the backup size is below 10 GB

Comment: Explore ftp/ftps backup using script , it should work with that